# Transfert node to an other disk

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a fast node running on a raspberry pi+SSD, I want to transfert it to a raspbery pi+SD card (512GB).

If I install the same os, with the exact same packages, then make geth.
Can I just copy the datadir of my geth node to get a fully synchonized fast node?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just on your new raspberry pi, set your --datadir to your ssd. this tutorial will help you.

https://kauri.io/#communities/Ethereum%20Node%20Runners/running-an-ethereum-full-node-on-a-raspberrypi-4-/#mount-the-ssd